# Reading variable-length numbers from stdout in java

Tags: java, arraylist

So far I have code to read the number of inversions in an arraylist, however I am reading from standard output and I encountered a problem,

```
public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Inversion inv = new Inversion(); 
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("What is your input?");

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) { 
        array.add(scan.nextInt()); 
    }       
}
```

When I read input like this I cant seem to stop unless I read in input that is not an int. I want to be able to redirect standard output to file. Is there anyway to know when to stop reading without using a "break key" such as zero or a character to break because input may come from a file.

Comment: In the case of reading a file, at some point you will hit the end of the file and the pipe will be closed.  But in the case of stdin, it will stay open until something closes it.  Are you planning to read from a file or from the console?

Comment: Console, I think file would be easier because I know I can close it, but I am not allowed to read from files

Comment: The only options which come to mind are having a "break" key or possibly using a counter and accepting a finite number of inputs from the console.